# Taking input for arrays

Tags: c, arrays, int, double, output

In doing a project for my computer science class, I came upon a problem with arrays. Basically, I have to take an input from the user for the number of years they want to input data for. I then have to use that input to create two arrays (one for the actual years they want the data for, and one for the data itself). I then have to print out the years and the data that the user just input.

The problem is that when I do this, the data for the years prints out fine, but the years themselves print out as random memory addresses. The other strang thing is that this only happens when I do three or more years. When I do two or less, everything else is fine. The variable for the years is an int and the variable for the data is a double.

```
int numberofyears;
printf("Enter the number of years you wish to take data for: " );
scanf("%d",&numberofyears); //take input for how many times arrays run

int years[numberofyears];
double dataforyear[numberofyears];

int a;
printf("Enter the years and their respective data");
for (a=0;a<numberofyears;a++){
   scanf("%d %lf",&years[a],&dataforyear[a]);} //take inputs for both arrays

int b;
for (b=0;b<numberofyears;b++){
   printf("%d %.2lf\n",years[b],dataforyear[b]);}
```

Input of:

```
Enter the number of of years you wish to take data for: 5
Enter the years and their respective data
1950 200.96
2000 300.55
```

Prints out:

```
1950 200.96
2000 300.55
```

Input of:

```
Enter the number of of years you wish to take data for: 5
Enter the years and their respective data
1956 325.21
1989 386.22
2003 400.00
```

Prints out:

```
0 325.21
1081671680 386.22
2003 400.00
```

And anything else beyond 3 years will do this. Though it seems like things beyond 5 years do not keep the last year like 3 does for whatever reason, if that helps.

Comment: Could you show us the initialization of `dataforyear` and the `printf` statement(s)?

Comment: Yeah, we need to see the printf code as well (and especially how you initialize your arrays)

Comment: The printf format for double is `%f`, not `%lf`.

Comment: If it helps anyone, 1081671680 == 0x40790000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
int years[numberofyears];
double dataforyear[numberofyears];
```

might be the problem. The compiler needs to know the size of your arrays at compile time. Otherwise you will have to allocate memory for your arrays. If your program isn't expected to read in a lot of data, you could always avoid allocating memory by specifying their sizes.

```
int years[10];
double dataforyear[10];
```

Comment: If that were the problem, it wouldn't have compiled.

Comment: @luserdroog I suppose that's probably true.. I honestly don't see any other issues in the code posted. hmm

Comment: Actually, I set both of the arrays to [100] and it seemed to fix the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Cheers! I think he's right.. It's a bit strange that it fixed the problem. Maybe your compiler has odd behavior with variable length arrays. Not sure! Glad it worked though

Comment: Now I feel bad about that other answer that said the same thing. I may have scared him away with my comment. Come back, dude, you were right, it seems!

Comment: @luserdroog I wouldn't worry about it. It's a bit of a mystery! I tried to recreate the same behavior but couldn't. It either didn't compile, or worked as intended (with the compilers I have anyway).

Answer (score 2):

How have you declared your `dataforyear[]` array?
If it is `float dataforyear[]` then change your scanf statement to
`scanf("%d %f",&years[a],&dataforyear[a]);`

else declare your array to `double dataforyear[]` if you want to keep your`scanf` statement as it is.